# Does a leap seconds exists in iOS?

Tags: ios, datetime, leap-second

I am preparing TCP/IP protocol between I/OS windows and embedded device. Some scenario will send current time as time stamp for some data. I use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) a format of time in packets. Do I need to solve a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) in protocol send from iOS to Windows/embedded device?

Comment: Why not just use GMT which is embedded into the phone?  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: iOS is a standard Unix based operating system. It's clock is kept in sync just like the rest of the world. So yes, it deals with leap seconds.